# java.lang.AssertionError : Mismatching of expected value and found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, assertion, testng-eclipse

I wanted check whether the text field value is same or not to the expected value which i mentioned on the code

```
@Test
public void tc001() {       
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).clear(); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("x@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).clear();driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("123456");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and  normalize-space(.)='Forgot Your Password?']) [1]/preceding::button[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Nadee")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Profile")).click();
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getText(),"sadas");    
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();
}
```

This is the ***text field*** which i need to get the value

input type="text" value="sadas" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter last name"

The code mentioned below got the **AssertionError**,
          Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getText(),"sadas");

I found the error as ,
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [sadas] but found []

How can i fix this?
And why i'm getting this error when expected value same to the found?(when manually checking the system)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the html code which you are accessing using above script

Comment: <input type="text" value="sadas" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter last name">

Comment: **java.lang.AssertionError: expected [sadas] but found []**
above exception means that the lastname input value is returning null or empty value. 
Maybe you need to add a wait statement after clicking profile button. Share your complete html page for exact solution.

Comment: WebDriverWait textfeild  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);     textfeild.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")));

Comment: I have updated my code as above after the profile click,but same result occurred

Comment: String lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getText(); and check whether it's returning any value or not.

Comment: share your whole the HTML page to understand your scenario completely. Not sure but maybe there are 2 inputs having same name("LastName") on page.

Comment: hi,i have check the html page(i cannot share it as it is belong to the my company),but there is no duplication of "LastName".And i tried out other textfield's as well(ex : email,mobile,FirstName).same results occurred

Comment: 1. Remove webdrvier wait and add Thread.sleep(5000); just for testing purpose.
2. Try using this
String lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']"));
String textValue = lastName.getAttribute("value"); 
System.out.println(textValue);

Comment: hi Waqar Nadir,thanks for your support.I have tried to print it.but nothing printed on console,nothing receives for value...

Answer (score 0):

This code will help to locate the particular text, this one is Javascript.

```
String expectedMessage = "Please enter password.";
    String message = w.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sign_in_div\"]/form/div/ul/li[2]/div")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue("Please enter password.", message.contains(expectedMessage));
```